# Box2D getPosotion error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I am working on a game . I am facing problem in box2d.
I have created a World and a Web (sprite,body) and then i am throwing web on touchend, and a tick selector which gets position of sprite and its giving error.

Here is tick selector
[image]

onTouchEnd

```
- (void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    if (freeBody) {
        [self schedule: @selector(tick:)];
        [self schedule:@selector(WebHitsFood:) interval:0.01f];

        freeBody->SetType(b2_dynamicBody);

        //this is the maximum force that can be applied
        const CGFloat maxForce = 600;


        //get the location of the end point of the swipe
        UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
        location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];


        //get the rotation b/w the start point and the end point
        CGFloat rotAngle = atan2f(location.y - startPoint.y,location.x - startPoint.x);

        //the distance of the swipe if the force
        CGFloat distance = ccpDistance(startPoint, location) * 0.5;

        //put a cap on the force, too much of it will break the rope
        if (distance>maxForce) distance = maxForce;

        //apply force
        freeBody->ApplyForce(b2Vec2(cosf(rotAngle) * distance, sinf(rotAngle) * distance), freeBody->GetPosition());

        //lose the weak reference to the body for next time usage.
        freeBody = nil;


    }
    self.isTouchEnabled = NO;

}
```

and Create Web Method

```
-(void) createWeb
{
    freeBodySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"web1.png"];//web_ani_6_1
    //freeBodySprite.position = ccp(100, 300);
    [self addChild:freeBodySprite z:2 tag:6];

    CGPoint startPos = CGPointMake(100, 320/1.25);

    bodyDef.type = b2_staticBody;
    bodyDef.position = [self toMeters:startPos];
    bodyDef.userData = freeBodySprite;


    float radiusInMeters = ((freeBodySprite.contentSize.width * freeBodySprite.scale/PTM_RATIO) * 0.5f);
    shape.m_radius = radiusInMeters;


    fixtureDef.shape = &shape;
    fixtureDef.density = 0.5f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 1.0f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.0f;

    circularObstacleBody = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);
    stoneFixture = circularObstacleBody->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
    freeBody = circularObstacleBody;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the GetPosition() is the problem? Try adding the line

float test = b->GetPosition().x;

just before the one giving you the issue to determine whether the issue is actually with GetPosition() or whether it is the myActor.position that is the source of the exc_bad_access.

Comment: i have added this line before myActor.position. and i am getting the same error on myActor.position.

Comment: So when you added this line before the previous line you did not get an exc_bad_access occur on it? That proves then that the body GetPosition() is not the cause of your problem and the issue has to do with the userdata of the ccsprite.

Comment: Ah, I see you're not retaining the 'freebodySprite' anywhere, it's lost. The userdata is just a pointer, you are responsible for keeping the object in memory somewhere. Keep it somewhere and that will resolve this. Right now after createweb() method completes the freebodySprite goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to fix that crash:

```
for(b2Body* b= world->GetBodyList(); b; B->GetNext())
{
    id sprite = b->GetUserData();

   if( sprite && [sprite isKindOfClass:[CCSprite class])
   {
         CCSprite *myActor = (CCSprite*) sprite;

         myActor.position = CGPointMake(b->getPosition().x*PTM_RATIO, b->getPosition().y*PTM_RATIO);

       myActor.rotation = -1 * CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle());
   }
}
```

Comment: i did add this code but when i am throwing the object my game pauses. and nothing is working than.. and there is no error as well.

Comment: I have used breakpoint but its not stopping on anywhere. but my game is hang

Comment: then comment these code and try...still same problem then its something else problem..without any code its impossible to tell..

Comment: It was working till i have added above code you have sent me.

Comment: so its not problem with above code, try to add exception breakpoint in xcode and debug.